# Html Codes in the Array do not Appear Properly?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I am trying to split words in a paragraph.I use the explode function for this.Works well when dividing words.But there are problems with the html codes in the paragraph.I wonder how can I show html codes without errors?

```
$text = '<p>Integer sodales risus nec tortor pulvinar faucibus.Donec vestibulum facilisis tortor id 
blandit.<a href="http://localhost/web/images/img47.jpg"><img class="aligncenter" 
src="http://localhost/web/images/img47.jpg" alt="text" width="600" height="338" /></a>
Vestibulum quis nisi ullamcorper, rutrum turpis eget, placerat nisi. Quisque efficitur augue iaculis 
sapien feugiat, pretium lacinia erat suscipit. Quisque id hendrerit orci, eget posuere dolor. Nunc 
consectetur ante sit amet euismod varius.</p>';

$ext[] = explode (" ",$text);
print_r($ext);
```

output:

```
 ...
 [11] => id
 [12] => blandit.
 href="http://localhost/web/images/img47.jpg"> class="aligncenter"
 [15] => src="http://localhost/web/images/img47.jpg"
 [16] => alt="text"
 [17] => width="600"
 [18] => height="338"
 [19] => />
 Vestibulum
 [20] => quis
 [21] => nisi
 ...

As seen in the example, '<a' and  '<img'  codes are not visible.
```

Comment: View the source of the page in the browser.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes it appears in the source code.But I want to show it in the array.

Comment: `$text = htmlentities($text);` first.

Comment: @AbraCadaver  So what should I do if I want to show this as a picture again?For example, combining the array (implode) and outputting it?

Comment: You should look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php llop through and split text only.